# How can you run powershell commands with a list of strings you set in c#?

Tags: c#, powershell

This Button works with the original code, but I wanted to put in the command as a list of strings (2nd part of code):

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        newProcessInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
        newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command ""C:\Windows\notepad.exe""";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo);
    }
```

Here was my attempt to place it as a list of strings, but it wouldn't work for some reason:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("\"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe\"");

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo[] arrayProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo[strings.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count(); i++)
          {
            arrayProcessInfo[i] = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            arrayProcessInfo[i].FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";

      //I commented this out to see if it could show me an error 

            //arrayProcessInfo[i].WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            arrayProcessInfo[i].Verb = "runas";

      //I wanted to see the error but not sure if I need to use something other than -noexit in the command line

            arrayProcessInfo[i].Arguments += @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command -noexit " + strings[i] + ""; 
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(arrayProcessInfo[i]);
            //MessageBox.Show(strings[i]);   //This does show the string output when not commented out
          }
        }
```

I did try this and it works, but wanted it to be a list of strings:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string string1 = "\"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe\"";
        var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        newProcessInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
        //newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command ""C:\Windows\notepad.exe""";
         newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command " + string1 +"";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`?  See examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked after lots of testing.

```
string[] strings = new string[1];
        strings[0] = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe\"";
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo[] arrayProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo[strings.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count(); i++)
        {
            arrayProcessInfo[i] = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            arrayProcessInfo[i].FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
            arrayProcessInfo[i].WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            arrayProcessInfo[i].Verb = "runas";
            arrayProcessInfo[i].Arguments += @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command " + strings[i] + "";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(arrayProcessInfo[i]);
        }
```